# ScrollView Not Working in android studio , desired output not coming

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

The output of the below code is not coming as the output required . Full Screen is not been covered in the scrollview .I am trying to use Constraint Layout inside the scroll view.Please help....... 
The contents of the constraint layout are getting overlaped and the full screen is not covered by constraint layout....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.libizo.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.873"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111"
            app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
            app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
            app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_mail"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.115"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute,VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/Login"
            android:layout_width="204dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.417"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
            fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
            fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
            fancy:fb_text="Login / Register"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
            fancy:fb_textSize="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_lock"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.268"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute,VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <com.libizo.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.873"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.268"
            app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
            app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
            app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Forgot_Password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot Password ?"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.527" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Google"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_google"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.884"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Phone"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_phone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.148"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Facebook"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.541"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.991" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[The Output for the following code is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3Pl.jpg)

Comment: can you share the output you want.

Comment: @Kunal Have you done drag and drop/ click and drag of the views?

Comment: try to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

You set wrong `Constraint` to view. Try like below. It will give you some idea and change it according your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_mail"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute,VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <com.libizo.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
            app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
            app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_lock"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_mail"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute,VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <com.libizo.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Email"
            app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#8f1f15"
            app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
            app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
            app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp" />

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/Login"
            android:layout_width="204dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
            fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
            fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
            fancy:fb_text="Login / Register"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
            fancy:fb_textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Forgot_Password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot Password ?"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Login" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Google"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_google"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Forgot_Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Phone"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Forgot_Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Facebook"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Google"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it worked to some extent......but still the desired output is not coming.....have a look to the output produced by your code  :- https://ibb.co/PjNHp5q

Comment: also the edittext should be little down from parent